# Why my (kernel) GCov doesn't work on linux 3.9?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, gcov

I had done as the "Documentation/gcov.txt" said.

Basic about mime:

```
$ uname -a
Linux turf.ivor 3.9.5 #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 00:51:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)

$ zcat /proc/config.gz | egrep "GCOV_|DEBUG_FS"

CONFIG_GCOV_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y

$ mount | grep debugfs
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)

# ls -la /sys/kernel/debug/gcov/ 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Jun 14  2013 .
drwx------ 17 root root 0 Jun 14  2013 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 0 Jun 14  2013 reset
```

I found nothing but a reset file (an empty file).

As "document" says:

```
 90 4. Files
 91 ========
 92                                                                                
 93 The gcov kernel support creates the following files in debugfs:
 94 
 95         /sys/kernel/debug/gcov
 96                 Parent directory for all gcov-related files.
 97 
 98         /sys/kernel/debug/gcov/reset
 99                 Global reset file: resets all coverage data to zero when
100                 written to.
101 
102         /sys/kernel/debug/gcov/path/to/compile/dir/file.gcda
103                 The actual gcov data file as understood by the gcov
104                 tool. Resets file coverage data to zero when written to.
105 
106         /sys/kernel/debug/gcov/path/to/compile/dir/file.gcno
107                 Symbolic link to a static data file required by the gcov
108                 tool. This file is generated by gcc when compiling with
109                 option -ftest-coverage.
```

What should I do?

Does gcov still support latest linux version?

Any advice, and thanks.

`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely gcc. Some newer versions no longer generate .ctors seections and are using .init_array instead. You can confirm this by doing a objdump -dr -j .ctors of one of your gcov enabled kernel objects.  If it returns no such section found, try .init_array.

I'm working on a fix for this right now trying to understand the arcane mysteries of replacing .ctors with .init_array in the do_ctors call of init/main.c.  It's not as simple as swapping the section names in vmlinux.lds.h

Sorry this is not yet an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following changes in vmlinux.lds.h file to add .init_array in .ctors section of vmlinux file  and it will work : -

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GCOV support for ARM is not enabled in Kernel.
Please refer below URL, apply 2 patches to your kernel and you will be able to see gcov file on target

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/JsvylFnag-Y

Answer (score 0):

For new kernel version above 3.7 or 3.8 you must be sudo user to get your gcda files.

`sudo su`

Now go to directory `/sys/kernel/debug/gcov/`

you will see the built linux code path.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and i think gcc is the curplit. When my gcc version was under 4.7, eveything seemly goes well. Otherwise the problem just like yous came out.

Why?

greebo52's answer is the answer.

How to solve?

you can use gcc under 4.7 or compile your own gcc 4.7. when you configure gcc 4.7, add this --disable-initfini-array.
like this:

./configure --disable-initfini-array ...(other options)